# Mongo db project a field not in the group

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, collections

I'm wondering if I can project field is not exist in the group. 
For example I have the below collections and I want the name of students who has highest soccer across all students

```
{ "_id" : 1, "Snmae" : Alex, "score" : 97}
{ "_id" : 2, "Snmae" : Sara, "socre" : 97 }
{ "_id" : 3, "Snmae" : Sam, "socre" : 93 }
{ "_id" : 4, "Snmae" : Dan, "socre" : 77 }


db.stuudent.aggregate( 
{$project:{_id:0,sname:1,score:1}},
{ $group : { _id : "", High_Score: { $max: "$score" }}}
 );
```

The desire output is

Sname: Alex  ,  score: 97

Sname: Sara  ,  score: 97

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data:

```
{ "_id" : 1.0, "Sname" : "Alex", "score" : 97.0 },
{ "_id" : 2.0, "Sname" : "Sara", "score" : 97.0 },
{ "_id" : 3.0, "Sname" : "Sam", "score" : 93.0 },
{ "_id" : 4.0, "Sname" : "Dan", "score" : 77.0 }
```

Query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$score",
            "names": { $push: "$Sname" }
        }
    },
    { $sort: { "_id": -1 } },
    { $limit: 1},
    { $unwind: "$names" },
    {
        $project: {
            "Sname": "$names",
            "score": "$_id",
            "_id": 0
        }
    }
])
```

Explanation:

- [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) - groups the students by score.
- [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) - sorts the documents by score in the descending direction.
- [$limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) - takes only first document (document with highest score value).
- [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) - splits "names" array into separated documents.
- [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) - generates the final results (documents with defined shape).